# Convert Decimal NCRs Code into UTF-8 in java (JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8

I was trying to decode string which in FARSI to UTF-8 but then i checked browser itself convert FARSI string into Decimal NCRs Code

How i can convert Decimal NCRs Code into UTF-8 ??

```
String farMsg = "عتباري";
String finalMsg = new String(farMsg.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
System.out.println("\n Farsi Message \n" + finalMsg);
```

when i am trying convert using above code it is working fine
but if i am using same string from an input box of `JSP` page its is giving me some output like this

```
&#1593;&#1578;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610;
```

What modification do I need to do for converting into same.

**EDIT**

> I entered `عتباري` in the jsp input box and in used `request.getParameter("faMSg")` to get the value and here i got `&#1593;&#1578;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610;` but i should get `عتباري`

Comment: what is the actual value that you get in `farMsg` from jsp page,

Comment: @dbw I entered `عتباري` in the jsp input box and in used `request.getParameter("faMSg")` to get the value and here i got `&#1593;&#1578;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610;` but i should get `عتباري`

Comment: where are you reading value by `request.getParameter("faMSg")` ? in servlet ?

Comment: No in other JSP Page ? which also have same page encoding

Answer (score 8):

I created a custom function which converts DecimalNCR to `String`.

```
public static String ConvertDecimalNCRToString(String hex)
{
    String myString = hex.replace("&#", "");
    String[] split = myString.split(";");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) 
    {
        sb.append((char)Integer.parseInt(split[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This converts successfully your supplied `String`.

**EDIT** I tested the above function with Chinese `游鍚堃`,`你好你怎么样` and Farsi (`عتباري` , and `مرحبا كيف حالك`) character it provided correct results.

Comment: If my string is like `تاریخ تولد من 1990/05/01 می باشد.` it is throwing an error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1990/05/01" java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:`

Comment: But as per your question you get the string in Decimal NCR format and Decimal NCR for above string is `&#1578;&#1575;&#1585;&#1740;&#1582;&#32;&#1578;&#1608;&#1604;&#1583;&#32;&#1605;&#1606;&#32;&#49;&#57;&#57;&#48;&#47;&#48;&#53;&#47;&#48;&#49;&#32;&#1605;&#1740;&#32;&#1576;&#1575;&#1588;&#1583;`

Comment: Is it that half of your input is coming in decimal NCR and some part as normal character

Comment: Yes, the string can contain numbers too

Comment: then you can alter the above logic little bit and add condition whether a character contains `&#` or not

Comment: @KodeCeeper can you provide the complete output that you get which you want to convert

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting content type to `utf-8` in jsp page :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
```

OR

```
<% @page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

UTF-8 is not default content type in jsp, and there are all sorts of interesting problems that arise from this.
Browsers will use the encoding of the page.So if you use `UTF-8` in all your pages, then most browsers will send all data in `UTF-8` encoding as well.

If your are reading textbox value in Servlet than You can tell your application server to treat any input as UTF-8, by calling,

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before reading value on server side.

**EDIT :**

To apply this setting globally so that you don't need to edit every individual JSP, you can also add the following entry to your /WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
</jsp-property-group>
```

Comment: are applying in web.xml file or in jsp page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is work fine - white space is the problem that I solved

```
Public static String ConvertDecimalNCRToString(String hex)    
  {
        String myString = hex.replace("&#", "");
        String[] split = myString.split(";");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        {
            char first = split[i].charAt(0);

            if (first==' ')

            {
                sb.append(" ");
                split[i]=split[i].substring(1);
            }
            if (split[i].isEmpty())
            {

            }else
            {
                sb.append((char)Integer.parseInt(split[i]));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```